# Mail an exchange server SMTP server response: 550-Verification failed

Tags: php, email, sendmail

How do I send an email to my exchange server? When I set the php.ini file with send_from="x@domain.com" it says 550 verification failed. How do I verify myself?

I am using SMTP: mail.domain.com

Comment: how are you sending the mail?

Answer (score 1):

Its probably a good idea to use a class like phpmailer http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/ to do this.

That way if you have multiple projects that need to send via a different account or different servers then you won't have any problems.

The error you're getting is because your exchange server requires authentication and your script isn't using authentication or its using the wrong information. I've never really relied on the built in php sendmail functions so I can't be 100% sure but I don't think it supports authentication. (I might be wrong on that point, but I still recommend a class that you can configure per script over a globally configured mail account)

Comment: If you really want to use the built in mail function and your exchange server is running on the same machine that is running php then turn off smtp authentication if the sender is from a local network and make sure your script uses the loopback address and not the public address to connect to the server. Please do not turn off smtp authentication all together. :)

Comment: Yep, although you could [code it yourself](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/exchange2010/exchange_2010_smtp_auth_login.htm#3_SMTP_Auth_Login_Plain), just letting a lib which has proven itself over the years take care of it gets my vote, +1.